# how to download muiltiple xsl file inside folder at once click

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excel-2007

i am saving my excel in specified  server path folder using **GridViewExportUtil**
i am creating the folder and saving multiple xsl inside it.

like as below

```
application root
|_ Exprotxsl
    |_folder1
    |    |_first1.xsl
    |    |_second1.xsl
    |    |_third1.xsl
    |_folder2
        |_first2.xsl
        |_second2.xsl
        |_third2.xsl
```

so how to download my all xsl file which is inside in folder1 and folder2. i mean,
in some location in client pc during download folder1 and folder2 should be created with all xsl.

Answer (score 0):

You can create archive first and then download one file with all *.xsl at once.